# Is it possible to avoid a dangerous collision with the ground after free fall by converting the potential energy into rotational kinetic energy?

Tags: kinematics, momentum, potential-energy

Is a human body able to survive if someone sabotages your parachute and you're in a free fall towards earth suddenly realizing that you have one out of two options left- either die or stand on the ground and directly converting all the potential energy into kinetic energy in form of a front roll? Would that be possible? Maybe we need to consider the type of ground too (muddy, soft ground, rocky ground,...).

Comment: One major issue would be the direction of the kinetic energy.  By the time you're near land, you've already converted most of the potential energy to kinetic energy (and lost an awful lot of energy to air drag); but that kinetic energy has increased your velocity vertically downwards.  Rolling wouldn't dissipate much energy if while trying to go horizontal, most of your body is trying to fall into the rest of it at incredible speeds.

Comment: The initial title and the PS seemed trivial and lacked seriousness, so I've edited them. Please avoid including phrases like "see body" in the question title... try to summarize your question instead.

Comment: you sure the rotation won't give you brain damage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hit something like a very large skateboard ramp, nearly vertical at first, then gradually getting less steep. With the right shape, there'd be a constant force on you giving you horizontal motion. The ramp could be friction-less, thus not necessarily making you rotate.

If you do not want to introduce a net horizontal motion, you could twist the ramp into a helix, giving the falling person a spiral motion.

Answer (score 2):

Converting kinetic energy to rotational energy does not dissipate linear momentum.  What *can* happen is that in converting some of the kinetic energy due to linear motion into rotational kinetic energy, the impact forces can be spread out in time and/or over the surface of the falling body; and this can reduce the amount of damage caused to the body.  All of the kinetic energy must be dissipated to stop the falling body, and all of the momentum must be dissipated as well.  Force x time = momentum, and force x distance = energy.  In a straight-down impact onto a hard surface, both time and distance are short so the forces are large.  Onto a soft surface, the impact time is stretched out (and so is the distance), so the forces are reduced.  Similarly, if the impact results in torques on the body, the impact time is stretched out and the forces are reduced. That is one reason we are taught to roll when we fall in martial arts and sports.  However, the terminal velocity of a freely falling human body is about 120 miles per hour.  Rolling on impact wouldn't help a bit.  There was one case several decades ago when a flight attendant fell from an airplane, landed on a haystack, and survived: *lucky* lady!

Comment: It was [this woman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vesna_Vulovi%C4%87) I assume.

Comment: I haven't been able to find the article about the woman I remember reading about.  The article about Vesna Vulović indicates that she was found in the wreckage of the plane. However, Wikipedia has a page [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Fall_survivors] that lists six people who survived falls from airplanes, including one whose fall was softened by pine branches and snow, and another who hit snow on a steep slope.